# How I create a table in EF and ASP.NET Core 5 MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework and ASP.NET Core 5 MVC with a SQL database in Visual Studio.

When I create the `DbContext`, the database and the first table are okay. But I'm trying to create a model and use the scaffold command to make a table (controller with views EF), I did but is no visualize in SQL objects or the using controller links.

How can I create more tables? Creating another project from zero?

Comment: Can you Edit the Question and add the Code you tried unsuccessfully, and also include a text copy of warnings or Exceptions if you got any?

Comment: `I'm trying to create a model and use the scaffold command to make a table (controller with views EF), I did but is no visualize in SQL objects or the using controller links` what do you mean? How do you scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Below commands are used for the dotnet CLI tool. I don't know if you use CLI or not but the logic should be the same with a `Visual Studio`'s function or something. I only use the CLI so I can't know.

To edit the database, you need

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

which I'll assume you've run already, since you have your first table.

When you make any changes and/or additions to your models, you have to make sure your `DbContext` has the model(s) in question in a `DbSet` or similar structure.

Then, you simply have to add a migration so the change/addition is registered. Simply run:

```
dotnet ef migrations add NameOfMigration
```

and then, just update the database so it saves the change.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

You can read my own notes on Entity Framework [here](https://github.com/Stratis-Dermanoutsos/Full-Stack-Notes/tree/main/Languages/Backend/Cs/ASPNET#entity-framework) or the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/).

Comment: thanks, i put DbSet in context and the code is created in Visual Studio BUT in the SQL  DB inside the .NETCORE app has no table. Im gonna  use the dotnet

Comment: @Morfeo this might help with the Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs